# Somehow creating a 64bit DLL with Borland C++ Builder

Tags: dll, 64-bit, c++builder, c++builder-xe2

I've created a 32bit DLL in Borland C++ Builder XE2 no problem.

I was tasked to create a 64bit version as well. After researching the "hows" I came to know that Builder does not yet support 64bit compilations.

After some digging around it looked as though the only way to do this ( or any kind of 64bit compiling) was to use visual studio express command lines. Thus I tried the following commands to try to compile:

```
CALL "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\SetEnv.Cmd" /x64
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\amd64\cl.exe" -IC:\projects\dll -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\9.0\include\windows\vcl" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\9.0\include\windows\rtl" -MD -LD C:\projects\dll\dll.cpp -FeMyDLL.dll
```

Running the above gives me the following error:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\9.0\include\windows\rtl\sysmac.h(162) : fatal error C1189: #error :  "System.hpp/sysmac.h and related headers need __declspec(uuid(..)) and __uuidof support"

Mucking about on Google only gave me some posts on adding #define DECLSPEC_UUID(guid) which doesn't help at all.

So my question is, has anyone ever successfully compiled a Borland C++ project (or an application / DLL created in Borland) for 64 bit (plus a step-by-step on how)?

Comment: Trying to #include the headers of one compiler and build it with another is a pretty guaranteed fail whale.  MSVC *does* support __uuid, something wrong with the test I guess.  Borland added a lot of non-standard keywords to the language so this is in general a lost cause.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot compile C++Builder RTL/VCL code with Visual Studio. You will have to either port the code to Visual C++ or other C++ compiler and use its frameworks instead of Embarcadero's, or else re-write the code in Delphi XE2 so you can continue using Embarcadero's RTL/VCL and the Delphi 64-bit compiler.